# How to Visually represents Parent->Child->Grand Child on Small screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, charts

I am looking for an idea for visual representation of Parent->Child->GrandChild for small screen like Iphone 5/6 etc.

I thought of representing it something like fusion chart ( my another question on it[[How to create slices of a multi level pie chart dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724786/how-to-create-slices-of-a-multi-level-pie-chart-dynamically])  but I am unable to get some breakthrough using javascript , CSS 3 and HTML 5.

I am looking for another idea for this representation on small screen.

Answer (score 0):

could you use some iteration of the google charts org chart or would that be too wide?

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldvo7qd0/1/

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

    data.addRows([
      [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Grandfather</div>'}, '', 'GrandParent'],
        [{v:'Rita', f:'Rita<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Grandmother</div>'}, '', 'GrandParent'],
      [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>'}, 'Mike', 'VP'],
      ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
      ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
      ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
  }
```

Comment: I am using similar chart for Medium screen like ipad. i need something for smaller screen. Also , i cannot use any third party library. Thanks for looking into it.